# Using Jquery to set required based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, input

I want to change the required attribute of an HTML input if the value of another input is larger than 8. (without submitting anything)

```
<input id="inputCheck" name="inputCheck" placeholder="" required="true" value="" type="number">
<input id="inputReact" name="inputReact" placeholder="" required="false" value="" type="text">
```

Basically if the value of inputCheck is larger than 8, set rquired of inputReact to true. I know how to change the attribute, problem is checking the value without submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a change event listener to the required input field.

```
$('#inputCheck').change(function() {
    const value = $(this).val();
    const rInput$ = $('#inputReact');
    if(value > 8) { // could also use parseInt(value) to convert value into number if it isn't already.
        rInput$.attr('required', true); 
    } else {
        rInput$.removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

Comment: cool, however you requested answer in jquery and accepted a pure JS answer :) just saying, no hard feelings.

Comment: It was the first one to come so I just accepted it, never posted before. I‘ve used yours though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input` listener

```js
let checkBox = document.getElementById("inputCheck")
, textBox = document.getElementById("inputReact")

checkBox.addEventListener("input", evt => {  
  if(evt.target.value > 8) textBox.setAttribute("required", true)
  else textBox.removeAttribute("required")
})
```

```html
<input id="inputCheck" name="inputCheck" placeholder="" required="true" value="" type="number">
<input id="inputReact" name="inputReact" placeholder="" required="false" value="" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>keydown demo</title>
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<form>
 <input id="inputCheck" name="inputCheck" placeholder="" required="true" value="" type="number">
<input id="inputReact" name="inputReact" placeholder="" required="false" value="" type="text">
</form>

 
<script>
var xTriggered = 0;
$(document).ready(function()
{
alert("ok");
$( "#inputCheck" ).keydown(function( event ) {

 var myLength = $("#inputCheck").val().length;

if((myLength+1) > 8)
{

$("#inputReact").attr("required","true");
}
});
 
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```